# Convert Date object format to date datatype. Doesnt work with pandas to_datetime function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with the following format for Dates- 201008 which would mean August 2010. I want to convert this object to Date datatype in Python

I used this code

```
datetime.strptime(df['DATE'].to_string(),'%Y%m').strftime('%Y-%m')
```

ended up getting a long error like this

```
ValueError: time data '0       200708\n1       200808\n2       201008\n3 
...
201008' does not match format '%Y%m'
``
```

Comment: Your pattern does not match your input.

Comment: So what can be done for the same. to_datetime function doesnt seem to work.

Comment: You can use this: `df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': ['202001', '200110']})`, `df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format="%Y%m")`, `df['formatted date'] = df['new_date'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m")`